# Unmarshal XML into interface

Tags: xml, go

If I have some JSON, I can Unmarshal into an empty interface:

```golang
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   raw := []byte(`
   {
     "regionalRating": {"rating": "TV-PG", "region": "CA"}
   }
   `)
   {
      var rating any
      json.Unmarshal(raw, &rating)
      fmt.Println(rating) // map[regionalRating:map[rating:TV-PG region:CA]]
   }
   {
      var rating map[string]any
      json.Unmarshal(raw, &rating)
      fmt.Println(rating) // map[regionalRating:map[rating:TV-PG region:CA]]
   }
}
```

but if I try the same thing with XML, it fails:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/xml"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   raw := []byte(`
   <regionalRating>
      <rating>TV-PG</rating>
      <region>CA</region>
   </regionalRating>
   `)
   {
      var rating any
      xml.Unmarshal(raw, &rating)
      fmt.Println(rating) // <nil>
   }
   {
      var rating map[string]any
      xml.Unmarshal(raw, &rating)
      fmt.Println(rating) // map[]
   }
}
```

I remember seeing an answer on here where someone had found a method to do this,
using something similar to my code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

No, it is not possible, at least not according to the first line in the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml@go1.20.1#Unmarshal):

> Unmarshal parses the XML-encoded data and stores the result in the value pointed to by v, which **MUST be an arbitrary struct, slice, or string**.

<sup>emphasis added by me</sup>

---

If you want to unmarshal the XML into an arbitrary type you'll need to implement the unmarshaling yourself. This is not too difficult however since the tokenization of the XML is already done for you by the [`Decoder.Token`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml@go1.20.1#Decoder.Token) method, all that's left for you to do is to look at each token and decide what to do with it.